# Can I add methods into def __init__?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

Using python 2.7.6, I have been trying to write a class that can extract pieces of xml data from a couple of xml files within a given zip file.  I want to be able to use any of the methods in any order once I am working with the class, so wanted the unzip stage to be behind the scenes, in the class.

It is the first time I have really tried to make real use of a class as I am quite new to python, so I am learning as I go.

I defined methods to unzip the data to memory and was using those methods in other methods - then realised it would be horribly inefficient when using multiple methods.  Since the unzipping step is necessary for any method in the class, is there a way to build it into the init definition so it is only done once when the class is first created?

Example of what I currently have:

```
class XMLzip(object):
    def __init__(self, xzipfile):
        self.xzipfile = xzipfile

    def extract_xml1(self):
        #extract the xmlfile to a variable

    def extract_xml2(self):
        #extract xmlfile2 to a variable

    def do_stuff(self):
        self.extract_xml1()
        ....

    def do_domethingelse(self):
        self.extract_xml1()
```

Is there a way to do something like I have shown below?  And if so, what is it called - my searches haven't been very effective.

```
class XMLzip(object):
    def __init__(self, xzipfile):
        self.xzipfile = xzipfile

        def extract_xml1()
            # extract it here

        def extract_xml2()
            # extract it here

    # Now carry on with normal methods
    def do_stuff(self):
        ...
```

Comment: Yes it is possible? What is the question? Why don't you just use the extract methods in `__init__` instead of defining them there?

Comment: How is that done? I've never seen it in an example. Does it have a name? It might help me search for one.

Comment: Do you mean define the extract methods as I do now, but call them in the init part? How can that work?

Comment: Why would it not? I'll post an answer.

Comment: I learnt C, I'm finding it hard to accept the order!

Comment: To accept the nature of Python's `__init__()`, look at its name. It is not a constructor, it is an **init**ializer! When you call your class (`xml_zip = XMLzip(my_xzip_file)`, an instance of the class gets instantiated in two steps: An object is constructed (the Python runtime's job, not your class's) and _then_ that object and any class call arguments are passed to `__init__()` for initializing the object. Because the object has already been created, methods can be called just like in any other method. Only the effect of running `__init__()` itself isn't there, yet, obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the `__init__` you can do whatever you want in order to initialize your class, in this case look like what you need is something like this

```
class XMLzip(object):
    def __init__(self, xzipfile):
        self.xzipfile = xzipfile
        self.xml1 = #extract xml1 here
        self.xml2 = #extract xml2 here

    def do_stuff(self):
        ...
```

if you want to do the extract part only once, then do it and save result in a additional attribute in the instance of your class.

I suspect that the extract procedure is very similar, so you can make it a function be inside your class or outside, that is up to your preference, and give additional arguments to handle the specificity, for example something like this

the outside version

```
def extract_xml_from_zip(zip_file,this_xml):
    # extract the request xml file from the given zip_file
    return result

class XMLzip(object):
    def __init__(self, xzipfile):
        self.xzipfile = xzipfile
        self.xml1 = extract_xml_from_zip(xzipfile,"xml1")
        self.xml2 = extract_xml_from_zip(xzipfile,"xml2")

    def do_stuff(self):
        ...
```

the inside version

```
class XMLzip(object):
    def __init__(self, xzipfile):
        self.xzipfile = xzipfile
        self.xml1 = self.extract_xml_from_zip("xml1")
        self.xml2 = self.extract_xml_from_zip("xml2")

    def extract_xml_from_zip(self,this_xml):
        # extract the request xml file from the zip_file in self.xzipfile
        return result

    def do_stuff(self):
        ...
```

Comment: Wouldn't your inside version call the function `extract_xml_from_zip` before it is defined? I think Python doesn't allow this. You can either write your function outside the class (as in Copperfield's first example), or define `extract_xml_from_zip` before defining `__init__`.

Comment: @yeshua the order of execution is not the same to the order of definition, all the stuff is defined and compiled first but not executed, the execution come when you run the code... try it yourself with a little example

Answer (score 3):

You can call any method you have defined in your class in your initializer.

Demo:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...    def __init__(self):
...        self.some_method()
...    def some_method(self):
...        print('hi')
... 
>>> f = Foo()
hi
```

I take from your question that you need to extract the files only once. Leave your class as is and use your extract methods in `__init__` and set the required attributes/variables for the extracted content.

For example

```
def __init__(self, xzipfile):
    self.xzipfile = xzipfile
    self.extract1 = self.extract_xml1()
    self.extract2 = self.extract_xml2()
```

This of course requires your extract methods to have a return value, don't forget that.

Comment: Excellent answer thanks, @timgeb, I have accepted the other just based on the options given if others look at the question.  Thanks though.